# JQuery .hide()/.show() with .prop() setting of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/chrisfrisina/DgN5E/).   I would like the content to be somewhat interactive, and just click the content to hide it.  To allow the user to bring it back if s/he would like to, the hidden portion appears in the `<aside>` section to the right.   I have the 'header' (Business Approach) working as it must remain as a Parent DOM element.   I have been struggling getting the children to work.   My current attempt for the children is/are this (also posted on the fiddle):

```
    //individual BA elements Toggle Buttons
    //Currently on, turning Off
        $('.block > .businessapproaches > section > input').on('change', function () {
            if (this.checked) {
            } else {
                var index = $(this).prevAll('section').length;
                $('.block > .businessapproaches > section').eq(index).hide();
                $('fieldset.businessapproaches > label').eq(index+1).show();
                $('fieldset.businessapproaches > input').eq(index+1).prop('checked' , false);
                console.log("off")
                console.log("left index: " + index);
                console.log($('.block > .businessapproaches > section').eq(index));
                console.log($('fieldset.businessapproaches > label').eq(index+1));
            }
        });
    //Currently off, turning On
        $('fieldset.businessapproaches > input').on('change', function () {
            if (this.checked) {
            } else {
                var index = $(this).prevAll('section').length+1;
                $('.block > .businessapproaches > section').eq(index-1).show();
                $('.block > .businessapproaches > input').eq(index-1).prop('checked' , false);
                $('fieldset.businessapproaches > label').eq(index).hide();
                console.log("on")
                console.log("right index: " + index);
                console.log($('.block > .businessapproaches > section').eq(index-1));
                console.log($('fieldset.businessapproaches > label').eq(index));
            }
        });
```

Sorry to post 2 questions in the same stack, but it seems relevant, and I'm trying quickly to get to a rep of 125 so I can post multiple questions without having to wait the prescribed time)

BONUS POINTS: Can tell me why the 'header' (Business Approach) is clickable by either the checkbox or the text, while the children are not?   Where is my error, as I will eventually hide the 'boxes' with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/guanxiaohua2k6/dpvAn/1/. I think it worked as you want.

I will show where to modify below.

```
@@ -10 +10 @@
-                    var index = $(this).prevAll('section').length;
+                    var index = $(this).closest('section').prevAll('section').length;
@@ -13 +13 @@
-                    $('fieldset.businessapproaches > input').eq(index+1).prop('checked' ,     false);
+                    $('fieldset.businessapproaches > input').eq(index+1).prop('checked' , true);
@@ -24 +24 @@
-                    var index = $(this).prevAll('section').length+1;
+                    var index = $(this).prevAll('input').length;
@@ -26 +26 @@
-                    $('.block > .businessapproaches > input').eq(index-1).prop('checked' , false);
+                    $('.block > .businessapproaches > section > input').eq(index-1).prop('checked' , true);
```

As to why the 'header' of children couldn't be clicked, the inputs' ids are duplicated with ones in <aside>.

Comment: 1: Can you follow up with a better explanation, since im not sure why you had to add the .closest() function, as well as setting the children to true and true, when the parent is false, then true.

2:  Oy, veh!, That's what I get for copying my dynamically generating HTML!,   thanks for the catch.

Comment: According to jQuery's description "Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.", prevAll only get preceding siblings. Therefore if you want to get the sections before, you should get current section first with closest(). I create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guanxiaohua2k6/MUbe2/. You can try it.